# How would you compute this integral?

Tags: integration

$$ \int \frac {1-\cos x}{(1+\cos x)\sin x} dx$$

I tried to expand the fraction by sin x and substitute t = cos x, so I got $$ \int \frac{(1-t)}{(1+t)(1-t)(1+t)} dt$$ here i could cancel out (1-t)... but what next? I don't know which formula should be used.

Comment: Doesn't the inside reduce to $1/(1+t)^2$?

Comment: yes, but what then?

Comment: Beside to Issac's comment, can't you solve $\int (1/u^2)du?$

Comment: It would be -1/u + c. So... 1/(1+t)^2 should be -1/(1+t) + c... after substitution -1/(1+cos x) + c, but right answer is 1/(1+cos x)... then why?

Comment: Check the sign. Using your substitution $t=\cos x$ you should get

$$\int \frac{1-\cos x}{\left( 1+\cos x\right) \sin x}dx=-\int \frac{1-t}{
\left( 1+t\right) \left( 1-t^{2}\right) }dt=-\int \frac{1}{\left( 1+t\right)
^{2}}dt$$

Comment: You are absolutely right. I overlooked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\int\frac{1-\cos x}{(1+\cos x)\sin x}dx=\int\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{(1+\cos x)^2\sin x}dx=\int\frac{\sin^2 x}{(1+\cos x)^2\sin x}dx=\int\frac{\sin x}{(1+\cos x)^2}dx$$ Now take $t=\cos x$ as you noted before.

Comment: good idea, thanks :)

Comment: @user50222: Welcome; but I just wrote what Issacs note. :)

Comment: You are so gracious and humble! +1